# simple PHP to MYsql filtering

Tags: php, mysql, text

I need to paste data received as e-mail text files into an html form that sends the data to a mysql database via a php file that filters the data into the relevant cells in the mysql table.

The data arrives and is copied into an input box like this:

```
First name: John
Last name: Smith
telephone: 01234 56789
```

What php would remove "First name:" from the string and post "john" into the first name column of the database likewise with "Last name" and "telephone"

building the html form and database is not a problem; my php though is not quite yet up to speed!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the *input box* a textarea ? if not what is it ?

Comment: If you can control the HTML form, why not set it up as three seperate input boxes?

Comment: try learning PHP, and build a simpler form with input boxes and labels

Comment: Have a look at [strpos](http://uk3.php.net/strpos) and [substr](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: @andrewsi I think the OP wants to automatically parse the data instead of manually pasting bits of it.

Comment: The point of this site is you give it a try and when you get stuck you ask for help, this is more like solve the whole thing

Comment: @lc - I expect so; but I'm a big fan of making life as easy as possible for myself

Comment: "Simple" is *not* a good term to describe what you mean to do, unless your data is *always* in the same form without spelling errors, abbreviations, etc.

Comment: If the format of the incoming data is consistent, then maybe you should use a regular expression to fetch the data. Something like `preg_match('/First\ name:(.+?)Last\ Name:(.+?)Telephone:(.+?)/isx', $email, $matches);`?

Comment: @andrewsi +1 I agree with you 100%.

Comment: yes, the input can be a simple text or comment box like the one that I am typing into now. The pasted data is always delimited by ":" then "space" then "line break"

Comment: yes allen213....I am stuck with the php!

Comment: @allen213...what part of "building the html form and database is not a problem; my php though is not quite yet up to speed!" Did you not understand? Simple php hints like Battle_707 gave are more appropriate. Please save the "I'm a really clever developer and have not got time for you" comments for the rocket-scientist friends that you no-doubt mix with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you receive plain text emails with data.

Then you want to parse it. If your 'labels' are automatically generated and consistent then you can parse it quite easily... say something like this:

Say you load your email text into a variable $email_content.

```
$lines = explode("\n",$email_content);
$array_of_values = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (str_pos(":",$line)!==false) {
        $temp_array = explode(":",$line);
        $array_of_values[trim($temp_array[0])] = trim($temp_array[1]);
    }
}
```

In the end you will have an array like this:

```
array(
    'First Name'=> 'John',
    'Last name' => 'Smith',
    'telephone' => '01234 56789'
)
```

Then you will be able to easily access whichever value you like by key and subsequently save it to database if you like.

There are certain assumptions though - that you only have : in lines that contain label:value pairs. Also end of the line char is always /n. But this is just a pointer not a ready made solution.